# How to change button color based on background?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I write in React. On the page I have a scroll up button.

[image]

When scrolling on some blocks, it is not visible due to the fact that the colors match.

[image]

How to make it so that when it touches certain blocks of the same color as the button, it turns white.

[image]

How to track the contact of a button with a specific block? What listeners to put?

Comment: What have you tried, Can you show us some code? So we can help you better.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The best option is to choose another color of the button. However, if your really need it, I guess, that while your button is position absolute it is out of the dom tree, so that you can not get where it crosses other dom elements. But you can define the position (x,y) of ythe dom element (in your case round button) on the window of the browser. After that define the position of the dom element with blue background and make event when position are equal. But it seems that in general this is unnecessary work.

Comment: Try using Intersection Observer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API I don't have a fully ready solution for you, but maybe it works. It has it quirks when watching absolute positioned elements, but try it out and see if it works for your usecase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the button is probably `position: fixed` or `position: absolute`, the easiest solution would be to give CSS property `mix-blend-mode` a try, instead of listeners, as there is no accurate way of telling the position w.r.t to background.
[Check this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)
Try to give `mix-blend-mode: difference;` for the scroll to top button.
Although I think in this case you will have the color yellow for the button when it overlaps blue.

Answer (score 0):

Although [Sanjay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74299621/18620006) "works", you really don't have much control over the styles you get, unless that `blend-mode:difference` is the look you're going for.
For more [fine grained](https://tnl1cc.csb.app/) control, you need to use the [`IntersectionObserver` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

There's really three steps to this process:

**1. Get the required options for IntersectionObserver constructor**

This means you need to find out the negative margins to set as the [rootMargin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#rootmargin) key. This key is part  of the configuration object of your IntersectionObserver instance.
In practice you would have to find the distance of your trigger element(in your case the floating action button) to the edges of the viewport. In the code snippet below, this is done using the `getDistanceToEdge()` function.
It's better to do it this way instead of statically setting your margins, since it dynamically infers the margins from the position set from your styles.

**2. Tell the observer what you wish to when triggered**

This is the [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#targeting_an_element_to_be_observed) which will trigger the new styles on your floating button. You need to check whether your elements are intersecting with the button using the `entry.isIntersecting` key, and then conditionally render the style.

**3. Setup the observer with elements you wish to cause the trigger**

The elements that scroll up causing your floating button to change color, should be passed to the observer, using the `observer.observe()` function.

The following code snippet really does all the setup you need. It won't trigger unless the element is actually underneath the button (the API internally checks vertical and horizontal overlaps).
For some reason I can't get it to work on iframes embedded in browsers. It could be something to do with the negative margins and multiple viewports.
It works perfectly on normal full page websites, as shown in this [hosted link](https://tnl1cc.csb.app/).

*One little caveat* is that consecutive elements that trigger the observer, will cause each other to cancel out, since the button enters the second area before fully leaving the first one. I'll leave it to someone else to figure out the specifics there.

```js
// get the element that reacts to background elements
const fabElement = document.getElementById("fab");

// what do you want to do when it overlaps?
function reactToOverlap(entries) {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) fabElement.classList.add("triggered");
    else fabElement.classList.remove("triggered");
  });
}

const observerOptions = {
  rootMargin: getDistanceToEdge(fabElement)
    .map((val) => `-${val}px`)
    .join(" "), // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#rootmargin for syntax
};

const observerInstance = new IntersectionObserver(
  reactToOverlap,
  observerOptions
);

// what elements do you want to trigger the change?
const elementsToTriggerFab = document.querySelectorAll(".triggeringContent");
elementsToTriggerFab.forEach((el) => observerInstance.observe(el));

/* Represents how far the element is from the edge of the browser, in all directions. */
function getDistanceToEdge(element) {
  const elementBounds = element.getBoundingClientRect();

  // top and left margins are identical to the pixel coordinates
  const top = elementBounds.top;
  const left = elementBounds.left;

  // bottom and right need to be subtracted from the viewport bounds
  const bottom = window.innerHeight - elementBounds.bottom;
  const right = window.innerWidth - elementBounds.right;

  return [top, right, bottom, left];
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 3rem;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#fab {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 1rem;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  transition-property: background-color, color;
  transition-duration: 0.5s
}

#fab.triggered {
  background-color: white;
  color: blue;
}

.normalContent {
  color: green;
  border: 10px solid green;
  height: 100vh;
}

.triggeringContent {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.triggeringContent.avoidFab {
  margin-right: 200px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="fab">Up</div>
    <div class="normalContent">Other Content</div>
    <div class="triggeringContent">Triggerring Content</div>
    <div class="triggeringContent avoidFab">Triggerring Content</div>
    <div class="normalContent">Problems coming up</div>
    <div class="triggeringContent">Triggerring Content</div>
    <div class="triggeringContent">Triggerring Content(Error)</div>
    <div class="normalContent">Other Content</div>
    <div class="triggeringContent avoidFab">Triggerring Content</div>
    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
```

Shoutout to [cloned](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4733161/cloned)'s comment for giving the idea for the solution.